# How to remove rows with nan values in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of data with nan values

[image]

I want to remove rows with nan values. I want this output:

[image]

Leaving only the rows without the nan values.

I tried to use this code

```
input = input[~np.isnan(input)]
```

However, the rows did not remove.

I also used

```
a = input[complete.cases(input), ]
```

But an error occurred. NameError: name 'complete' is not defined

Comment: "complete.cases" is for R

Answer (score 1):

Dataframe:

```
   values_1  values_2
0     700.0       NaN
1       NaN     150.0
2     500.0     350.0
3       NaN     400.0
4    1200.0    5000.0
```

You can try this:

```
df = df.dropna()
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Outputs:

```
   values_1  values_2
0     500.0     350.0
1    1200.0    5000.0
```

Comment: Got an erro : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dropna'

Comment: by the way, I edit the input data, Instead of "Nan" it must be "nan".

Comment: what's type of "nan"? string or np.nan

Answer (score 1):

Given numpy array as

```
import numpy as np
input = np.array([[1,1,0,np.nan], [1,1,1,30], [1,0,1,np.nan]])
```

try

```
output = input[~np.isnan(input).any(axis=1)]
```

gives output as

```
[[ 1.  1.  1. 30.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

input = input[~np.isnan(input).any(axis=1)]

any(axis=1) reduces an m*n array to n with an logical or operation on the whole rows.